# How to delete object property?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, boolean

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) the delete operator should be able to delete properties from objects. I am trying to delete properties of an object that are "falsey".

For example, I assumed the following would remove all of the falsey properties from testObj but it does not:

```
    var test = {
        Normal: "some string",  // Not falsey, so should not be deleted
        False: false,
        Zero: 0,
        EmptyString: "",
        Null : null,
        Undef: undefined,
        NAN: NaN                // Is NaN considered to be falsey?
    };

    function isFalsey(param) {
        if (param == false ||
            param == 0     ||
            param == ""    ||
            param == null  ||
            param == NaN   ||
            param == undefined) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

// Attempt to delete all falsey properties
for (var prop in test) {
    if (isFalsey(test[prop])) {
        delete test.prop;
    }
}

console.log(test);

// Console output:
{ Normal: 'some string',
  False: false,
  Zero: 0,
  EmptyString: '',
  Null: null,
  Undef: undefined,
  NAN: NaN 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `delete test[prop]` instead of `delete test.prop` because with the second approach you are trying to delete the property `prop` literally (which you doesn't have in your object). Also by default if a object has a value which is `null`,`undefined`,`""`,`false`,`0`,`NaN` using in a if expression or returns false, so you can change your `isFalsey` function to

```
 function isFalsey(param) {
     return !param;
 }
```

Try with this code:

```js
var test = {
        Normal: "some string",  // Not falsey, so should not be deleted
        False: false,
        Zero: 0,
        EmptyString: "",
        Null : null,
        Undef: undefined,
        NAN: NaN                // Is NaN considered to be falsey?
    };

    function isFalsey(param) {
        return !param;
    }

// Attempt to delete all falsey properties
for (var prop in test) {
    if (isFalsey(test[prop])) {
        delete test[prop];
    }
}

console.log(test);
```