# Javascript deleting object literal item(s) inside loop

Tags: javascript, object, stack, literals, splice

Hey all I am trying to delete a few items inside my object:

```
if (e = j[a].apply(j, g), e !== c && e !== j)
    $.each(j.data[0], function (key, value) {
       console.log(key, value);
       j.data.splice(1, 1);
    });

return h = e, !1
```

[image]

However, that does not seem to delete the item **environment** sine that is **#1** and **bomDescription** is **#0**.

I also tried:

> **j[0].pop()**
>
> **j.data[0].pop()**
>
> **j.data[0].splice(1, 1)**

Which non of the above work or cause an error.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete object property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571651/how-to-delete-object-property)

Comment: Is the content of `data[0]` an object or an array? Your title says 'object' but your code suggests an array.

Comment: @Mark_M I thought it was Object Literals

Comment: But you're calling `splice()` that's an array method.

Comment: Well then I'll go back to my last sentence in my OP - **What am I doing incorrectly?** :)

Comment: **data[0]** refers to the position the data is in that's presented in an HTML Table on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your object looks something like this (as it may seem from that image).

```
const j = {
  data: {
    bomDescription: "hjtyj",
    environment: 2,
    ...
  }
}
```

Then to delete the `environment` property you can use `delete` statement like this.

```js
const j = {
  data: {
    bomDescription: "hjtyj",
    environment: 2
  }
}

console.log(j.data);
delete j.data.environment;
console.log(j.data);
```

**EDIT**

To delete property based on its value you can do this.

```js
const j = {
  data: {
    bomDescription: "hjtyj",
    environment: 2
  }
}

const removePropertyByValue = (obj, value) => {
  for (const prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj[prop] === value) {
      delete obj[prop];
    }
  }
}

console.log(j.data);
removePropertyByValue(j.data, 2);
console.log(j.data);
```

**EDIT II**

If the data property is an array of objects then you can do this.

```js
const j = {
  data: [{
    bomDescription: "hjtyj",
    environment: 2
  }]
}

const removePropertyByValue = (obj, value) => {
  for (const prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj[prop] === value) {
      delete obj[prop];
    }
  }
}

console.log(j.data[0]);
removePropertyByValue(j.data[0], 2);
console.log(j.data[0]);
```

Comment: thanks for the example - however - I wont know the name (key) of the item I will be deleting.

Comment: @StealthRT Then based on what are you going to delete it?

Comment: It will be a number so in my example I put a static number of 1.

Comment: @StealthRT I am sorry but I don't understand. What will be a number? Object properties are not ordered. Do you mean that you want to delete property/ies that have number as thier value?

Comment: Yes @matus I will be checking to see if **something = key** and if it does then delete it.

Comment: @StealthRT Now it deletes property based on provided value.

Comment: Error: {
  "message": "Syntax error",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 20,
  "colno": 45
}

Comment: @StealthRT You can try now, I have changed it so that the data property is an array of objects.